# 2020 Taxes - How will I handle a new dependent?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

My sister in law lived in Las Vegas, Nevada and did her taxes for 2019. Her husband suddenly passed away unexpectedly in September. She sold her house in March of this year 2020 and paid off the remaining balance of her house. She was left with around 180k after selling the house. She has decided to move in with us in a different state and I am willing and able to be responsible for her. That means food, shelter, I am going to use my money and help her out for a while at least through 2020 and maybe further past that.

My question is this would mean she is a dependent to me in my taxes. She has a valid social security number so when I do my taxes for next year (I already did my 2019 taxes) do I just claim her as a dependent? Or is this not as simple as I think and would need to still do her taxes separately as she sold a house in march of 2020? I just know that her expenses I will be taking on for quite some time. I know she has the money to pay me back but I don't expect her or want her to pay me back for this, me and my wife want to cover her for the time being.

I know its way too early to talk about taxes for 2020 but I want to have a head start in understanding this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk through the IRS's [Interactive Tax Assistant for determining who you can claim as a dependent](https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/whom-may-i-claim-as-a-dependent).  The rules for 2020 haven't been published but, presumably, will be pretty similar to 2019 other than slight adjustments to certain limits.  My guess is that the stumbling block would be whether your sister-in-law had an income of more than ~$4,200 (the final number hasn't been published and might change a bit from 2019).  If so, you won't be able to claim her as a dependent.

Assuming you are allowed to claim her, you'd simply do your taxes and claim her and she'd do her taxes and indicate that someone else can claim her as a dependent.  You may want to do both sets of taxes both ways-- with and without claiming her as a dependent-- to see which way the aggregate taxes are lower.  It is possible that being claimed as a dependent costs her more than it saves you.

Comment: "It is possible that being claimed as a dependent costs her more than it saves you." That is generally not possible, since pretty much all the tax effects of being a dependent are determined on whether you *can be claimed* as a dependent, not on whether you are actually claimed as a dependent. So if the OP is allowed to claim the sister-in-law, then all the tax effects of that already apply to the sister, even if the OP does not actually claim her.

Comment: @Justin Cave - I took the tax assessment but when it asks for relationship the drop down doesnt really have "sister in law".  Since I file a joint return with my wife can I still pick "sister" since it is my wifes sister?  I dont like the answer "No relation / none of the above" ?

Comment: @JonH - I see a "brother-in-law or sister-in-law" option if you scroll down.  It's just above the "No relation" option.

Comment: @JustinCave - How in the world did I not see that!  I kid you not I looked and read through the list twice.  I guess I need to be more patient and careful - I see it now thanks.